# How to make a searchable dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, search, drop-down-menu

I want to create a `dropdown` in which you can also search for options.

I need a `dropdown` that gets info from my `DB` when I load the page. I can then click the `dropdown` as normal and see it's content (lets say: Facebook or Google).

I shall also be able to search in it, so at the top where I click to see the content, I could for example type "Fa" and then it would show the content that have "Fa" in it, (in this example Facebook only).

I don't know where to start making this. I'm looking for some finger points at where to look at, how this can be made, link to an example, etc.

Comment: try looking here http://www.jque.re/plugins/forms-controls/searchabledropdown/

Comment: Hi! Do give http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic a glance.

Comment: @Satya - thank you SO much! that was actually exactly that i was looking for. Been looking for hours with out a result. Thanks! -- Epodax - I see i might need some more info on the topic. I'll get that right next time. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Hey there. Happy that your question got solved. I edited to keep out some unnecessary details, such as thanks or sorry for a weird question. These are somewhat considered as noise, as they are not directly linked to your question. Your question may feel short, if you think I edited out something I shouldn't have, feel free to edit it back in, but I think this is the bare minimal question you could have asked to get your answer.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier thanks for the edit, and info on why. Helps to get finger points on what can be done better :-) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Satya's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333133/satya) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841788/how-to-make-a-dropdown-with-search-function?noredirect=1#comment47809665_29841788)

There's actually a [jQuery plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsearchdropdown/) that does this, with a nice set of configuration options:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").searchable({
        maxListSize: 100,                       // if list size are less than maxListSize, show them all
        maxMultiMatch: 50,                      // how many matching entries should be displayed
        exactMatch: false,                      // Exact matching on search
        wildcards: true,                        // Support for wildcard characters (*, ?)
        ignoreCase: true,                       // Ignore case sensitivity
        latency: 200,                           // how many millis to wait until starting search
        warnMultiMatch: 'top {0} matches ...',  // string to append to a list of entries cut short by maxMultiMatch
        warnNoMatch: 'no matches ...',          // string to show in the list when no entries match
        zIndex: 'auto'                          // zIndex for elements generated by this plugin
    });
});
```

here's an [example](http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/)